# Cannot marshal 'parameter #': There is no marshaling support for nested arrays. c#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, 2d, marshalling

I am trying to call native dll. 
 Signature of dll function looks like this

```
extern "C" BOOL FunctionName(TCHAR param1[][MAX_PATH],LPTSTR param2, int nCount);
```

now I want to call this function from c# code, I tried following

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate bool FunctionName(MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]char[][] param1,
                                                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string param2,
                                                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]int nCount);
```

when I try to create delegate for function pointer using following code,

```
FunctionName PFunctionName = (FunctionName)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptrToFn, typeof(FunctionName));
```

I get run-time error "Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': There is no marshaling support for nested arrays.".. How to solve this?

Comment: did you solve this issue?